# Taylor Approximations

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm learning about Taylor approximations and I must be missing something. The textbook I'm working with shows that a function $f(x)$ can be approximated near $z$ like this:

$\hat{f}(x) = f(z) + \nabla f(z)^T (x - z)$

where $\nabla f(z)$ is an $n$-vector, the gradient of $f$ at the point $z$.

My question is, if we know $f(x)$ and it's differentiable, why would we need to approximate it? Why can't we just work directly with $f$?

Comment: Often, the Taylor approximation is significantly simpler than the actual function $f$. For example, consider $f(x)=(1+x)^n$. Near $x=0$, we have the Taylor approximation $f(x)\approx1+nx$. Now if I want you to tell me what $1.0013^5$ is accurate to four dp, the Taylor approximation immediately gives $1.0065$. That was a slightly trivial example, but I hope you can see why we would prefer simpler forms if possible.

Comment: You approximate a function when you cannot or don't want to compute it. The Taylor approximation is a mere polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to know how much is
$e^{0.35}$.

How to do? I don't know and nobody else knows.

With Taylor you expand $e^x$ around $x=0$ and get
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+O\left(x^5\right)$$
Thus you can compute, with a little patience if you libe in 18th century,

$$e^{0.35}\approx 0.35\, +1+\frac{0.35^2}{2}+\frac{0.35^3}{6}+\frac{0.35^4}{24}$$